# Order not preserved in a Bean list - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a bean created this way:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    List<TestItem> testItemsList(TestItem item1, TestItem item2, TestItem item3) {
        return List.of(item1, item2, item3);
    }
}
```

I have this list autowired in other service.

```
@Service
public class ItemsServiceImpl implements ItemsService {

    private final List<TestItem> testItems;

....

 @Override
    public Result useItems() {
        testItems.forEach(item -> {
            log.info("component: "+item.toString());
        });
}
```

The thing is, when I try to use it in a simple `forEach` loop, the order is different, I get `item3, item1, item2` logged.

I've also played with it a little bit and added a constructor:

```
public ItemsServiceImpl(List<TestItem> testItems) {
        this.testItems = testItems;
        log.info("constructor order" + Arrays.toString(testItems.toArray()));
    }
```

and it also prints the values in incorrect order: `testItem3, testItem1, testItem2`.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Various questions here. Is your `TestItem` object within Spring's context? Can you show the example of where you inject the list?

Comment: thanks for reply @akortex! Edited the question to give you more insight

Comment: Still your edit does now show how you create the various instances of the `TestItem` objects. Are those created by spring?

Comment: Well actually you are **not** using the list created by the ` testItemsList` bean method. But you are given all `TestItem` implementations in a collection by Spring. The code would still work, in the same way, if you removed the `testItemsList` method. A typed collection as a dependency is a special use-case for Spring. If you want the list you would need to add an `@Qualifier` to specify which one to use. But it is probably easier to add an `@Order` to your `TestItem` classes and that will preserve the order as well (without an additional bean).

Comment: First of all you did not provide a library which is used in "List.of(item1, item2, item3);" So we can not check documentation how it works. You assume that it should add items one by one. Try to create new list and use .add instead.

Also we don't know how you use this method testItemsList, maybe you pass parameters already unordered. Try to print out them/use debug and check before using List.of method in testItemsList.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **not** using the list created by the  `testItemsList` bean method. What you are given is a list of all `TestItem` implementations by Spring. This is explained in [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation) of the Spring Reference Guide.

In fact your code would still work in the same way even if you would remove the `testItemsList` method.

You have 2 ways to solve this.

1. Add an `@Qualifier("testItemsList")` next to the `@Autowired` annotation (or on the constructor).
2. Remove the `testItemsList` and place `@Order` on your `TestItem` implementations for the order you want them in.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what was happening!